# Kivy - TextInput text show in Label text when Button is clicked (Not KV Lang)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

How to make text that I enter in the TextInput field (textA) will show in the Label (labelA) by using a button?

Every time there is new inputs, when the button is clicked, the labels will show the latest inputs.

Problem here when I use:
self.textA = TextInput(text='ss')

When I type new text and I click the button, the label always show 'ss'. Its not updating the new input.

Hope someone can show the method - just in python, not the Kivy Languange

Thanks

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class One(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(One, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        # text input
        self.textA = TextInput(font_size='60sp')
        self.add_widget(self.textA)
        self.add_widget(Two())


class Two(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Two, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'

        # Button
        self.btnA = Button(text='Show')
        self.btnA.bind(on_press=show)
        self.add_widget(self.btnA)

        # Output
        self.labelA = Label(text='Result Here From Input')
        self.add_widget(self.labelA)


def show(value):
    Two().labelA.text = str(One().textA.text)
    x = Two().labelA.text
    y = One().textA.text
    print(x)
    print(y)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return One()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use `One()` or `Two()` you are creating new instances of `One` or `Two`, and these new instances are unrelated to the instances that are in your GUI. If you want to access the instances in your GUI, you must arrange for that. For example, in the `One` class, you can save  reference to the `Two` instance:

```
class One(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(One, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        # text input
        self.textA = TextInput(font_size='60sp')
        self.add_widget(self.textA)
        self.two = Two()  # save a reference to the Two instance
        self.add_widget(self.two)
```

Since the instance of `One` is the root of the `App` (returned by the `build()` method), you can access it from the `App`. Then your `show()` method can become:

```
def show(value):
    one = App.get_running_app().root
    two = one.two
    two.labelA.text = one.textA.text
    x = two.labelA.text
    y = one.textA.text
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Comment: Thanks John Anderson. I test and its working. Actually, I have trouble (hard to understand) to call other widget from another Class. I know it is easy to write using KV language, but i'm in learning process (understanding) the code writing in Python first.

I forgot to add Two() inside One(). Actually, this code was part of my code which I have another layout (the main layout - Stack Layout). I have One() and Two() inside my Main Layout.

Comment: Alright, so to make this working I need to (always) check which is the root of the App (returned by the build() method). I will try on my actual code and hope its working there.

Just asking, is the any other than this > App.get_running_app().root  - to access/call the one() class?

Again, thanks!

Comment: Ok its working on my actual code. I guess I understand this - "App.get_running_app().root.one.textA.text" = (rootWidget).(class).(widget).(widgetProperty). Thanks!

Comment: If you make your `show()` method into a method of the `TestApp` by placing it within the `TestApp` class definition and adding a `self` argument (like `def show(self, value):`). Then the first line can become `one = self.root`. Of course, that requires a change to the `bind` command: `self.btnA.bind(on_press=App.get_running_app().show)`.

Comment: Oh, its like that, i see. Thank you for your time and helped me out. :-)